# Using RSpec to loop through multiple spec groups

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, automation

I'm somewhat new to this so bear with.

I'm trying to execute several groups of tests independently via `RSpec::Core`

```
# Example
spec_groups = [['spec', 'spec2'], ['spec3', 'spec4']]

spec_groups.each do |spec_group|
  RSpec::Core::Runner.run([spec_group])
  RSpec.clear_examples
end
```

Two groups of specs - I want to loop through and run them all via the `RSpec::Core::Runner`.

`RSpec.configuration.fail_fast = true` will skip remaining specs in a group if any fail (if from group 1 `spec` fails it will not run `spec2`) but also seems to prevent any further groups from being run at all.

**Question**

If a spec from a group fails - how do I skip the rest of that group and move onto the next one?

Comment: It's uncommon to do this programmatically. Would an answer using the CLI be useful?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - possibly.. but this is a small part of a much larger test suite

How would you solve this via the CL?

Comment: CLI docs: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-7/docs/command-line